# SQL Same Date but different Times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm collecting data about entering or exiting the office in a table.
Now I need to do reports about these data but I'm having problems with this date, time record.

```
EDATE      ENAME      ETIME      EINOUT      ESABUN
20190502   AAA        083615     IN          6112                
20190507   AAA        083255     IN          6112                   
20190507   AAA        085022     IN          6112
```

I want the lasted ETIME of This user(AAA).

```
EDATE      ENAME      ETIME      EINOUT      ESABUN
20190502   AAA        083615     IN          6112                
20190507   AAA        085022     IN          6112
```

This is my sql.

```
SELECT
  [EDATE], 
  [ENAME],
  [ETIME],
  [EINOUT],
  ESABUN
 FROM [RDCA].[dbo].[HISTORY]
 WHERE ESABUN = '6112' AND  [EDATE] LIKE '201905%' AND [EINOUT] = 'IN'
 ORDER BY EDATE
```

Comment: `ORDER BY EDATE, ETIME`??

Answer (score 0):

You could use `group by` for this
The idea is to group all rows on all fields, except for the ETIME
Then you can grap the highest time value for each row
The grouping will make sure you have no duplicate rows

```
SELECT EDATE, 
       ENAME,
       max(ETIME) as ETIME,
       EINOUT,
       ESABUN
FROM   RDCA.dbo.HISTORY
WHERE  ESABUN = '6112' 
AND    EDATE LIKE '201905%' 
AND    EINOUT = 'IN'
group by EDATE, ENAME, EINOUT, ESABUN
ORDER BY EDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by the columns you want to be unique and use max() on the time column to get the highest for every group.

```
SELECT EDATE, ENAME, max(ETIME) as maxTime
FROM RDCA.dbo.HISTORY
WHERE ESABUN = '6112' 
  AND EDATE LIKE '201905%' 
  AND EINOUT = 'IN'
GROUP BY EDATE, ENAME
```

I removed the columns from the SELECT clause that you already have a given value for due to your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query. You need to transform your time into a valid datetime field before doing the sorting.

```
select * from (
select [EDATE], 
  [ENAME],
  [ETIME],
  [EINOUT],
  row_number() over (partition by 
        ESABUN order by cast(concat(left(ETIME, 2), ':', substring(ETIME, 3, 2), ':', right(ETIME, 2)) as datetime) DESC) as rn
FROM [RDCA].[dbo].[HISTORY]
WHERE ESABUN = '6112' AND  [EDATE] LIKE '201905%' AND [EINOUT] = 'IN') t1
where t1.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code where I use CAST as DATE for the EDATE column. Then I just checked the date range between >= '2019-05-01' and <'2019-06-01'  as I guess you are looking for data only from MAY of the year-

```
SELECT CAST(edate as date), ENAME,MAX(ETIME),EINOUT,ESABUN
FROM your_table
WHERE CAST(edate as date)  >= '2019-05-01' 
AND CAST(edate as date) <'2019-06-01'
AND ESABUN = '6112' 
AND [EINOUT] = 'IN'
GROUP BY CAST(edate as date), ENAME,EINOUT,ESABUN
```